# How do I clear anything from a list exept one thing? (python)

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have this list:
`list = ['hello','world','spam','eggs']`
and I want to clear everything from that list EXCEPT 'world'.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for this as:

```py
l = ['hello','world','spam','eggs']
only = [item for item in l if item  == 'world'] # ['world']
```

if you want to do it for multiple words you can store you filters as this:

```py
l = ['hello','world','spam','eggs']
filters = ['hello', 'world']
only = [item for item in l if item  in filters] # ['hello', 'world']
```

or you can also use the `filter` function as this:

```py
l = ['hello','world','spam','eggs']
only = filter(lambda x: x == 'hello', l) # ['hello']
```

In totaly, consider now to call your varibles by the type name, calling something `list` override the `list` constructor, which can lead for other prolbems in the future

Comment: Correction in second code: only = [item for item in l if item in filters]

Comment: Thank you very much, I ended up doing: l = l[1].

Comment: @Roy well no problem, but your answer is very specific for this list, you want to do more generic stuff, also consider makr my answer as currect if you thing so :)

Answer (score 1):

another solution is to check if 'world' exists in your list. If not assign an empty list.

```py
list = ['hello','world','spam','eggs']
if 'world' in list:
    list = ['world'] * list.count('world')
else:
    list = []
print(list)
```

Comment: This is not true if there is two 'world' in the list

Comment: Your solution perfectly suits for his question. I just gave another option.

Comment: But your option is worng, consider there is two `world` in this list, its going to give me only one of them in a list... `['world', 'world']` would return `['world']`

Comment: I updated my answer, to fit for that scenario. Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: Looks rather complicated and inefficient.

Comment: In case that hint wasn't big enough: I think it would be better if you removed three lines.

Comment: I didn't catch the hint. You are welcome to edit my answer. As I am learning python, it would be a help for me.